# Averaging based on a value of the cell using Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

So we have this activity to average values based on an hourly basis using excel vba.

Basically, what we are tasked to do is to average the values of cells separately.

An average for 9 PM to 10 PM, 10 PM to 11 etc. I've looked to many different methods and I still can't figure it out how to do that.

I know this can be easily done using a pivottable or using averageif but we are tasked to do this in excel vba.

This is my current code:

```
Sub test() 
    Dim a As Collection
    Dim lastrow As Integer 
    Set a = New Collection
    lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    If Sheet1.Range("A1").Value > TimeValue("09:00:00") Then
    For x = 1 To lastrow
    y = Cells(x, 2).Value
    a.Add (y)
    Next x

    For Z = 1 To a.Count
    f = a.Item(Z) + f
    Next Z
    Range("C1").Value = (f / a.Count)

    ElseIf Sheet1.Range("A1").Value < TimeValue("09:00:00") Then
    For x = 1 To lastrow
    y = Cells(x, 2).Value
    a.Add (y)
    Next x
    For Z = 1 To a.Count
    f = a.Item(Z) + f
    Next Z

    Range("C2").Value = (f / a.Count)
    End If
End Sub
```

This is how my data looks like:

[image: table]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: A) dont just drop some code, explain where exactly it breaks for you B) dont use screen shots for information that is purely text. Please take the time and remove the image, and put a bit of example data as pure, formatted text.

Comment: Using `Option Explicit` and declaring all or your variables could help improve the quality of your code. Picking variable names which are longer than 1 letter (unless they are simple loop indices) could also help. `a` as the name of a collection is a somewhat obscure choice. Finally, using a consistent pattern of indentation would also help. These are mostly aesthetic considerations, but unaesthetic code is frequently buggy code.